# asp .net mvc 5 dropdownlist SelectList no validation attributes

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

Inside model I have data annotations:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "SelectCategory", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyProject.Properties.Resources)), Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "SelectCategory", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyProject.Properties.Resources))]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

and two situations:

**Situation1**

Inside controller I have

```
    List<Category> categories = db.GetCategories();
    ViewBag.CategoryId = categories;
```

Inside View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryId, "Id", "Name", 2), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Html result:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="CategoryId">Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Category must be a number." data-val-range="Select category" data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="Select category" id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId">
        <option value="0">---Select---</option>
        <option value="1">Cat1</option>
        <option value="2">Cat2</option>
        <option value="3">Cat3</option>
    </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CategoryId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have validation attributes inside 'select' element, but no selected element

**Situation2:**

Inside controller I have

```
    List<Category> categories = db.GetCategories();
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "Name", 2);
```

Inside View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Html result:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="CategoryId">Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId">
            <option value="0">---Select---</option>
            <option value="1">Cat1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="2">Cat2</option>
            <option value="3">Cat3</option>
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CategoryId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no validation attributes inside 'select' element, but I have selected element

Could anyone explain me what is wrong? What should I do to have validation attributes and selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot use the same name for the `ViewBag` property as your model property. Change the `ViewBag` property to (say) `ViewBag.CategoryList`

Secondly you `categories` appears to contain an item with `ID=0` and `Name="Select"` so all your options have a value (zero is an integer so its valid) and you will never get an error message. Remove that item from `categories` and use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList, "Id", "Name"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This will render

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Category must be a number." data-val-range="Select category" data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="Select category" id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId">
    <option value>---Select---</option>
    <option value="1">Cat1</option>
    <option value="2">Cat2</option>
    <option value="3">Cat3</option>
</select>
```

Note the first option has no value, so if this one is selected, the `Required` validation error will be displayed.

Finally, to set the selected item when the page is first rendered, assign it to the property in the controller before you pass the view

```
model.CategoryId = 2;
return View(model);
```

and the the 3rd option("Cat2") will be selected by default.

Comment: why isn't data-val-range = "1" coming into effect?